# Custom Recovery, Custom Rom for Micromax Canvas Juice 3 Plus q394

Tags: custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery, xposed-framework

I have Micromax camvas juice 3 plus q394 i want an custom Recovery as well as custom rom i want to xposed my device but i searched on good for many hours but didn't get instead of a stock rom if anyone has custom Recovery and custom rom please share the link.

Answer (score 0):

**Apparently there was no shared construction, to make short no TWRP/CWM or even custom ROM were made for your device.**
Which means you two options, see three:

- Build your own custom recovery and adapt it to your phone using the basic TWRP sources available on Github for example
- Make your own request on the XDA forum which is specialized enough on the subject for me to recommend it to you, but there is no guarantee that someone will want to necessarily look into your case
- The ultimate option is, as they say, a phone call to a friend, in short, assuming you know someone who has the knowledge to do the job.

**Wishing you the best of luck for the future.**

Comment: Thanks for your response @Rom if it is possible can u provide a link how to build custom rom for mtk devices will be so helpful.

Comment: Porting an existing sources of custom ROM isn't easy and it's the most of time 50% useless to follow a thread because u could get some various unknow error(s). You can follow this thread but i don't think that it will works: https://sites.google.com/site/portingteams/home/how-to-port-custom-roms-for-all-mtk-chipsets, personally i will follow this thread: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2754145.

Comment: Thanks for help @Rom And can i convert this https://www.androidgsmbd.com/resurrection-remix-v5-8-5-nougat-custom-rom-for-mt6582-kernel-3-10-54-lp/  rom to my device because both has same chipset as well as kernel version or suggest any bug free custom rom.

Comment: Itsn't a task like "converting", you don't have to convert a file format to another. If you must to porting a custom ROM to your device, so fork RR sources on Github to your one and modify them, compile, and test it, by it could become hard regarding hardware issues u could get.

Comment: I mean porting that rom link above by replacing files that u suggested from stock rom to port rom like i want to port Resurrection Remix v5.8.5 which is running on kernel 3.10.54 mt6582 same as my device can i give it a try to port?